# ubuntustudio 12.04 unable to recognize sound hardwares on my desktop pc

Tags: 12.04, sound

my general system info:
ubuntu 12.04 (precise)
kernel 3.2.0-23-lowlatency (#31-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT Wed Apr 11 02:24:03 UTC 2012)
Sound card AMD nee ATI SBx00Azalea (Intel HDA) rev 40
NVIDIA UNIX x86_64 Kernel Module  295.40  Thu Apr  5 21:37:00 PDT 2012

Answer (score 0):

You may try to disable the integrated sound card on your motherboard, and enable only the sound card you have on your BIOS.

Comment: this is the link to output of step 3 of sound trouble shooting procedure: http://www.alsa-project.org/db/?f=0aa3618e5c2f5730abe048a43051888ea88ac5e7